# Water pipe rapid knocking - only in early hours of morning, outside tap problem? (UK)

Tags: plumbing

Old house. We started getting a rapid knocking in pipes a few months back. usually at somewhere between 1am and 5am, but sometimes earlier turning water on anywhere stops it, but it comes back again, usually.

There is an outside tap connected to float valve to top up pond in case of critical drop in water level. which is always on. Turning this off seems to stop it *mostly*, but there are occasions when it still does the knocking when this tap is off.

Another outside tap, higher up (house built into hill) that has a bit of a leak out of "stem" when turned on.

This is driving us insane, and can't work out what the critical element is. It sounds like it is a trapped air problem. 
Is it

- temperature drop overnight
- water not being run overnight (e.g. would do it during the day but taps being used)
- air ingress through higher outside tap causing the knocking
- the float valve (but why still happens when that tap is turned off)

Going to replace the valve in the higher tap, but anyone any other ideas?

---

EDIT 1:

- Replaced higher outside tap (had seized up, so couldn't just do
  washer) - No change
- Discounted work on supply outside - spoke to
  Yorkshire Water and there has been no change - awaiting call back
  from engineers.
- Discounted temp difference (warm / cold nights)
- Discounted the lower outside tap with float valve on as have been
  turning off tap at night, but still get knocking.

Current working hypothesis - higher pressure at night due to reduced demand on the network is causing the tapping, probably in the house stop tap - this is a bit weepy, so wonder if the washer is knackered in there.

Comment: Are you close to other users who might be demanding water at odd times? like farms?

Comment: Were there any plumbing changes in your house, neighboring houses or council works roughly at the time this started?

Comment: Not that we're aware of. Residential street. Although, coming to think of it, I do remember seeing a Yorkshire Water van outside around the time it started.

Comment: Silly question maybe - have you got a water softener which is recharging overnight, perhaps?

Comment: No. Nothing fancy like that. Just a simple old yorkshire house. :)

Comment: Thanks for the update. I don't have any ideas for you, but I'm sure someone will at some point. Don't give up on us yet!

Comment: Spoken to the utility company - they have suggested maybe turning the external stoptap down slightly. this tallies with my current thinking We live in a very high pressure area (bottom of Yorkshire Dales)  - it is likely that high pressure is causing this. Why now? Well, overnight there is less demand on the network, so pressure is higher. Why did it start 3 months ago? Lockdown. Businesses are closed. Water usage is generally quite low at the moment. So the double effect might be causing the problem at night. Tricky bit now is reaching the external stop tap at the bottom of a metre long shaft